# Pointer to smart pointer, purpose

Tags: shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Can anyone explain how does this work.

```
shared_ptr<T> *p = new shared_ptr<T>(x);
```

Should I do `delete p; p = NULL;`

Thank you

Comment: Who wrote this? For what purpose?

Comment: This is auto generated by SWIG from c++ code. I don't know who wrote

Comment: Your question contains the word "purpose". More context could help us determine the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
shared_ptr<T> *p = new shared_ptr<T>(x);
```

This is extremely non-idiomatic, not recommended, not good design.

`shared_ptr<T>` is for automatic memory management: you don't have to `delete` the object managed by `shared_ptr`. You need to make sure that

- `x` points to a `T` object allocated with `new`
- no other code tries to deallocate `x`

For some reason the code allocates a `shared_ptr` with `new`: the *automatic* memory management tool (`shared_ptr`) is managed *manually* here: you must remember to `delete` the `shared_ptr` when you don't need *it* (and not earlier), "it" being the tool whose *sole purpose* is to do avoid the risk of forgetting to do a delete or doing it too early.

> Should I do `delete p; p = NULL;`

Yes you need `delete p;` and `p = NULL;` is optional but necessary if other code might need to check whether `p` points to an object.

An analogy would be to have an alarm clock to wake you up, setup the alarm at time T, remove the battery in the clock, then ask a friend to put the battery back in the alarm clock at time T so it can wake you up.

At any rate, you should question the quality of the tools that produce such code.

Comment: Thank you very much